# Analytic continuation and convergence of a Riemann zeta related function

Tags: nt.number-theory, cv.complex-variables, prime-numbers, riemann-zeta-function

The functions in question are

$$L(s)=\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{\lambda(k)}{k^s}=\frac{\zeta(2s)}{\zeta(s)} \mbox{ and } L^*(s)=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{\lambda(k)+(-1)^{k+1}}{k^s}=\frac{L(s)+\eta(s)}{2},$$

where

- $\lambda(k) = (-1)^{\Omega(k)}$ is the [Liouville function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville_function)
- $\Omega(k)$ is the [prime omega function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_omega_function), counting the number of prime factors of $k$ including multiplicity
- $\zeta$ is the [Riemann zeta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_zeta_function) and $\eta$ is the
  [Dirichlet eta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_eta_function)
- $s=\sigma + it$ is a complex number
- $p_1, p_2,\dots$ denote the primes with $p_1=2$

An equivalent discussion could be based on the sister [Moebius](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%B6bius_function) and [Merterns function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mertens_function), but here our focus is on Liouville. The notations $L_n$ and $L_n^*$ are used to denote the first $n$ terms of the series representing respectively $L(s)$ and $L^*(s)$ when $s=0$. The asymptotic behavior of $L_n$ has well-known deep implications on the Riemann Hypothesis (RH), discussed later in this post.

**Note**: the series defining $L^*(s)$ might or might not converge if $\frac{1}{2}<s\leq 1$ (that's the purpose of my question), however the formula $L^*(s)=(L(s)+\eta(s))/2$ is valid only for $\Re(s)>1$ because the series defining $L(s)$ converges only for $\Re(s)>1$ (at least according to Wikipedia, see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_omega_function#Dirichlet_series)).

My main question can be stated in simple words:

**My question**

Does the series representing $L^*(s)$ converge and is it an analytic function if $\Re(s)>\frac{1}{2}$? Probabilistic arguments in favor of a positive answer are discussed in the appendix. Assuming the answer is yes, then $L(s)=2L^*(s)-\eta(s)$ is an analytic continuation of the original $L(s)$, from $\Re(s)>1$ to $\Re(s)>\frac{1}{2}$. Consequences are discussed in the next section.

I computed $L^*(s)$ for various $s$ with $\frac{1}{2}<\Re(s)\leq 1$ using the first million terms of the series, and compared with $L^*(s)=\frac{1}{2}\Big(\eta(s)+\frac{\zeta(2s)}{\zeta(s)}\Big)$ computed by Mathematica: the first three digits are identical. In particular, $L^*(1)=\frac{\log 2}{2}$ and the analytic continuation gives $L(1)=0$.

**Discussion**

The sequence $\{\lambda(k)\}$ consists of $+1$ and $-1$ that seem rather randomly distributed, though not perfectly randomly, but supposedly randomly enough (see [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/391736/normal-numbers-liouville-function-and-the-riemann-hypothesis)) as to imply the Riemann Hypothesis (RH) - still a conjecture at this point. For instance, if you look at runs of $+1$ or $-1$ (subsequences of consecutive $+1$ or consecutive $-1$) the probability for a run to be of length $m>0$ is equal to $2^{-m}$, as in a sequence of i.i.i. Bernoulli trials. More about this is discussed in the appendix. Yet this is not enough to make the series for $L(s)$ converge if $\Re(s)\leq 1$. Also, it seems there is a little bias in the sequence $\{\lambda(k)\}$, which might favor $L_n$ to be negative more frequently than positive, unlike perfect random walks. For instance, if $1<n< 906150257$, then $L_n$ is always negative (see [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/391736/normal-numbers-liouville-function-and-the-riemann-hypothesis)), but not at $n=906380357$, thus disproving [Polya's conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P%C3%B3lya_conjecture). That bias might disappear when $n$ becomes extremely large.

Now if you replace $\lambda(k)$ by $\lambda^*(k)=(\lambda(k)+(-1)^{k+1})/2$ corresponding to the terms in the series defining $L^*(s)$, the distribution of run lengths (if you ignore the terms $\lambda^*(k)$ equal to zero), is significantly altered. This would also be true, with the exact same impact, if you apply the same trick to i.i.d. Bernoulli trials or other sequences with similar distribution of $+1$ and $-1$. In the sequence $\{\lambda^*(k)\}$, assuming you omit the zero terms which do not contribute to the sums $L_n^*$ or $L^*(s)$, the probability for a run to be of length $m>0$ is now equal to $2\cdot 3^{-m}$, down from $2^{-m}$ for the original sequence $\{\lambda(k)\}$. This means that on average, runs are now much shorter, to the point that it makes the series $L^*(s)$ converge even if $\frac{1}{2}<\Re(s)\leq 1$. In essence, our trick is what gets us an analytic continuation from $\Re(s)>1$ to $\Re(s)>\frac{1}{2}$. Transforming $L(s)$ into $L^*(s)$ is the same trick as transforming $\zeta(s)$ into $\eta(s)$, though in the latter case, it extents analycity from $\Re(s)>1$ to $\Re(s)>0$.

An interesting question is whether you can infer some useful result about $\lim \sup_{n \rightarrow \infty} L_n$ from the smoother $L^*_n$, as the $\lim\sup$ in question is intimately connected to the Riemann Hypothesis (see my previous post [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/391736/normal-numbers-liouville-function-and-the-riemann-hypothesis)). Another curious facts is:

$$\sum_{k=1}^n \lambda(k)\Big\lfloor \frac{n}{k}\Big\rfloor =\lfloor \sqrt{n}\rfloor ,$$

where $\lfloor \cdot \rfloor$ denotes the integer part function. This formula is mentioned [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/1605.02727), and it allows you to compute $\lambda(k)$ recursively without using a table of prime numbers. Finally,

$$\zeta(s)=\frac{\zeta(2s)}{2L^*(s)-\eta(s)} = \frac{1}{2L^*(s)-\eta(s)}\cdot\prod_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{L(2^k s)}$$

gives (by successive applications of the first equality) an infinite product for $\zeta(s)$ converging (and analytic) if $\Re(s)>\frac{1}{2}$. The roots of $\zeta(s)$ in the critical strip $\frac{1}{2}<\Re(s)<1$ (if any, RH says that there are none) are identical to the poles of $L^*(s)$, or in other words, to the roots of $1/L^*(s)$ in the same strip.

**Appendix**

Here we show what would happen if the numbers $\lambda(k)$ were replaced by independent random variables $X_k$ taking value $1$ with probability $\frac{1}{2}$, and $-1$ with the same probability. This is pretty much (but not exactly) the way the $\lambda(k)$'s are behaving. Let's define

$$Z=\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{X_k}{k^s}.$$

Here $Z$ is a [complex random variable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_random_variable), and $s=\sigma +it$. Its expectation is zero, and its variance is given by

$$Var[\Re(Z)]=Var[X_1]\cdot\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{\cos^2(t\log k)}{k^{2\sigma}},\\
Var[\Im(Z)]=Var[X_1]\cdot\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{\sin^2(t\log k)}{k^{2\sigma}}.$$

Both series converge if $\sigma=\Re(s)>\frac{1}{2}$. In that case $Var[Z]=Var[\Re(Z)]+Var[\Im(Z)] =Var[X_1]\cdot \zeta(2\sigma)$. A formula related to the characteristic function, if $\tau$ is a real number, is the following:

$$E[\exp(i\tau Z)]=\prod_{k=1}^\infty \cos(\tau k^{-s}) .$$

Comment: Since the series for $\eta$ converges, the series for $L^*$ converges iff the one for $L$ converges. You've stumbled upon a statement equivalent to RH again.

Comment: The function $L$ is equivalent to $\zeta$ in $\Re s >1$ in a well-defined sense (Bohr equivalence) and Turan prefered it in his RH research;for $C(x)=\sum_{n \le x}\frac{\lambda(n)}{n}$ there are famous results of Turan relating this function with RH (or weaker versions); it is known that if $C(x)$ would be nonnegative for large $x$ RH would follow but that result is false as $C$ takes infinitely many negative values; however estimates of how negative $C$ can be imply results about the zeroes of RZ (eg if for some $a,c>0$ we have $C(x) > -c\frac{\log^a x}{\sqrt x}, x \ge x_0$ then RH true)

Comment: @Wojowu: True for $\Re(s)>1$, but I don't think so for (say) $s=0.9$. In particular I computed $L^*(0.9)$ using is series definition,  and it agrees with Mathematica. But you can't compute $L^*(0.9)$ based on $L^*(s)=(L(s)+\eta(s))/2$, because the series defining $L(s)$ does not converge for $s=0.9$. And according to Wikipedia (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_omega_function#Dirichlet_series) it only converges for $\Re(s)>1$. Or am I missing something?

Comment: Have you read Titchmarsh's book yet? (Probably not, because it takes about a year to read such a book.)

Comment: @GHf: I quickly looked at all the material but without trying to understand any proof yet. Got 2 other books on the subject: H.M. Edwards and A. Ivic, and I have received them all. Of course, that is just the beginning.

Comment: If you have a series of the form $\sum a_k+b_k$ and you know $\sum a_k$ converges, then $\sum a_k+b_k$ converges iff $\sum b_k$ converges (and then $\sum a_k+b_k = \sum a_k+\sum b_k$).

Comment: OK, but there is no point in trying to do research on the Riemann zeta function before you mastered the basics. Your questions reveal that you are not familiar with the basics. You should study those books for a few years, and then come back with questions.

Comment: @GHf: I think you are right. Probably should keep the research to myself, I have no plan on trying to prove RH anyway. I just got intrigued by the behavior of the $\lambda(k)$'s. I learn a lot by personal research and love it, but I should not post in this group a question that I know I should never submit to a journal.

Comment: Questions are good - if they are of research level. Your questions are usually not of research level, and they tend to be lengthy, exactly because you are not familiar with the background theory. I don't want to discourage you to be curious and ask original questions. Those are very good things and part of being a scientist. It's just that it takes a lot of studying before one can come up with good questions.

Comment: @GHf: In my case, there are a number of unusual factors why I have asked so many questions, many seemingly looking amateur. 1) I like the MO platform because of its math formatting capabilities (I need to find an alternative). 2) I have my own very popular blog for machine learning experts, but it's hard to post math formulas, and I can not risk to pass for an idiot - many followers are very math-savvy in my audience. 3) I was a promising statistician with top publications long ago (but not a mathematician) and I did achieve the promises - ....

Comment: @GHf: (Continued) this puts me in a situation where I'd like to offer a decent award to anyone who solves any of these problems in a way I or people I trust can understand it: RH, Goldbach, Collatz, or randomness of digits of $\pi$, $e$, $\sqrt{2}, \gamma, \log 2$. It would not be a prestigious award of course, but with a much better dollar amount than (say) the Fields Medal. 4) I have to find some mentor in number theory who can help me with my own problems, akin to starting a PhD (let's say a master to begin with) in the areas I am interested in - experimental and probabilistic number theory

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let $s\in\mathbb{C}$ be any point with $\Re s>0$. The Dirichlet series of $\eta(s)$ converges, hence $L(s)$ converges if and only if $L^*(s)$ converges.

For $\sigma_0>1/2$, it is also known that $L(s)$ converges in the half-plane $\Re s>\sigma_0$ if and only if $\zeta(s)$ has no zero in that half-plane.

Combining the previous two statements, it follows that $L^*(s)$ converges in the half-plane $\Re s>1/2$ if and only if the RH is true.

The above results do not change when we restrict to real numbers $s$.

**P.S.** The Wikipedia page does not say that $L(s)$ only converges for $\Re s>1$.

Comment: I was talking about the third display in the section "Dirichlet Series" in the Wikipedia entry. It says that $|z|<2$ and $Re(s)>1$ (I assume for convergence) and here $z=-1$. But they could be wrong, they got the product wrong anyway I think; should be $1-z/p^s$, not $1+z/p^s$ in the product unless I am mistaken. I will redo my numerical computations anyway, because (unless some mistake), I could not get $L(0.9)$ to converge, but got $L^*(0.9)$ to converge to the correct value.

Comment: @VincentGranville: The Wikipedia page defines the Dirichlet series for $\Re s>1$, because in that range we know convergence, and for $z=1$ you cannot replace $\Re s>1$ by $\Re s>0.999$, say. For $z=-1$ we conjecture that the Dirichlet series actually converges for $\Re s>1/2$: this is equivalent to the RH.